# Android Debugger acting strange

Tags: android, debugging, intellij-idea

Not sure what is going on. When I start the debugger in Intellij (using Genymotion emulator), before the main activity even starts I encounter the following errors:

```
09-28 07:49:27.487      531-574/system_process E/WifiStateMachine﹕ Failed to reload STA firmware java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: command '1 softap fwreload eth1 STA' failed with '501 1 SoftAP command has failed'
09-28 07:49:27.495      531-574/system_process E/WifiStateMachine﹕ Unable to change interface settings: java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '4 interface ipv6privacyextensions eth1 enable' failed with '400 4 Failed to set ipv6 privacy extensions (No such file or directory)'
09-28 07:49:28.595      531-574/system_process E/WifiConfigStore﹕ Error parsing configurationjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/misc/wifi/ipconfig.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
09-28 07:49:28.979      531-531/system_process A/NetworkManagementService﹕ problem enabling bandwidth controls
    com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector$NativeDaemonFailureException: command '5 bandwidth enable' failed with '400 5 Bandwidth command failed'
            at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.execute(NativeDaemonConnector.java:391)
            at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.executeForList(NativeDaemonConnector.java:327)
            at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.execute(NativeDaemonConnector.java:292)
            at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.prepareNativeDaemon(NetworkManagementService.java:348)
            at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.systemReady(NetworkManagementService.java:224)
            at com.android.server.ServerThread$2.run(SystemServer.java:972)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.systemReady(ActivityManagerService.java:9363)
            at com.android.server.ServerThread.initAndLoop(SystemServer.java:949)
            at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:1190)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and also

```
libcore.io.BlockGuardOs@526ef778
libcore.io.ErrnoException: stat failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I have no network code in my app, nor do I ever create any file in my code except for an SQLite database, which isn't even accessed in the main activity. I am completely lost...any suggestions on what these errors might mean? When I run the app normally, it starts up fine (it probably is just passing/ignoring the exceptions).

All I did recently was add a custom preference, but even when I rolled back changes, the debugger still encounters the errors.